# I want to re-generate part of a random generated paragraph created from arrays

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I am not entirely sure what to even search to find a solution here, but essentially I have a random text generator that creates a writing prompt from a series of arrays. The behaviour I want to add to it is the ability to "reroll" any of the individual random elements by clicking on them. Here's what the current function looks like that gets returned when the button is clicked.

```
function art_prompt() {
  return (
    '<p>' + 'The main character is a ' + get_three_random_words(personality) + ' ' + get_random_word(gender) + 
    ' who ' + get_random_word(frequency) + ' ' +  get_random_word(flaws) + ' and ' + get_random_word(frequency) + 
    ' ' + get_random_word(flaws) + '. The character is paired with ' + get_random_word(atmospheres) + 
    ' atmosphere, set ' + get_random_word(places) + ' during ' + get_random_word(time) + '.<br><br>' + 
    'The scene portrays ' + get_random_word(portrayals) + '.<br><br>' + '<strong>Bonus restriction:</strong> ' + 
    get_random_word(bonus_restrictions) + '.' + '</p>'
  );
}
```

So essentially, each of the `get_random_word(array)` functions I want to be a clickable element that generates a new random string from the same array. I have tried something where each one has a button concatenated around it and create a separate function for each array that is being brought in, but I want a more elegant solution if one exists.

Also I realize it's a bit janky of an implementation, but it's all I knew how to do when I started on it.

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have figured out a working solution. Just wrapped each object in a button, like this:

`'<p>' + 'The main character is a ' + '<button onclick="rollPersonality1()" class="reroll personality1">' + personality[rand1] + '</button>, '`

Using the buttons is a bit janky but it seemed to do the trick in this instance. I ran into another issue where I was trying to run the onclick function the same way I did for a static button, but it didn't work because the selector outside the function was no good. So the function for the above looks something like this.

```
var rollPersonality1 = () => {
  var PersonalityElement = document.querySelector('.personality1');
  PersonalityElement.textContent = randomPersonality();
}
```

I doubt this will help anybody else, but if it does that's awesome! If anyone has a more elegant way of doing this, I am not super happy with the messiness of what I came up with. So lay it on me!